# Error: Could not autoload puppet/face/node_aws/bootstrap

Tags: amazon-web-services, puppet, devops, puppet-enterprise, puppetlabs-aws

```
puppet help node-aws
```

> Error: Could not autoload puppet/face/node_aws/bootstrap: cannot load
>   such file -- guid Error: Could not load help for the face node-aws.
>   Please check the error logs for more information.
>
> Detail: "Could not autoload puppet/face/node_aws/bootstrap: cannot
>   load such file -- guid"
>
> Error: Try 'puppet help help help' for usage

Could anyone please tell me how can I resolve this error?

Comment: What command are you trying to run?

Comment: # puppet help node_aws

Answer (score 0):

1. gem install guid
2. gem install fog
3. vi ~/.fog

:default:
  :aws_access_key_id: XXXXXXX
  :aws_secret_access_key: XXXXXXXX

4. puppet module install puppetlabs-cloud_provisioner

Comment: Hi Mohamed yes i did that already. but still i am getting the same error.

Comment: What version of ruby do you use?